Accessing static member of nested template class
I have a templated class (Outer) and want to create a nested template class based on an enum of the class. This inner class has static variables, so they will need to be defined outside of the class to be accessible.
template <class T>
class Outer
{
private:
  enum InnerType {foo, bar /* etc */};
  
  template <InnerType U>
  class Inner
  {
  public:
    static int x;
  };

public:
  // access Inner<>::x
  void print() { std::cout << Inner<foo>::x << std::endl; }
};

// somehow define Inner<>::x

I've tried multiple different variations on the syntax in the accepted answer here but I can't seem to get it working. It compiles if I replace the enum with a class for each value, but the enum is much more explicit. Is it possible to use an enum here?

Depending on which version of the C++ standard you're targeting, you can define it inline: inline static int x = 0; Note that this is a C++17 feature.

That would break encapsulation, add a getter to your outer class. Code usingOuter should NEVER have to depend on internals of a class. And this is even more true of global variables (which static members are). Also in C++ use enum class now, and print (output functions should never be part of a class either). Don't get discouraged by my comments, I am just seeing some design flaws here :)

You can also use inline constexpr int x{42}; (from header file, use static constexpr otherwise. which will not make it a global variable at all (but a compile time constant), the {42} will also assign the (compile time) value.

As I mentioned in the staging ground, use inline with c++17

I can't seem to get it working Post a verbatim error message so it can be indexed by web search engines and your question become useful to other users that get similar errors.

I think the question is clear enough to be answerable. OP wants to know a way to define the static member outside the class template.

Remember that a template isn't a full definition, it only becomes one when you use it with the template parameter filled in.


so they will need to be defined outside of the class

That is not necessarily true. With c++17 we can use inline to provide the definition inside the class template as shown below.
If you're using pre-c++17 standard, see the first solution. Note the use of the enum keyword in pre-c++17.
So there are two ways to solve this depending on the c++ standard you're using as shown below.
Pre C++17
Here we provide an out-of-class definition:
//-------------------------vvvv---------------------------->note this enum keyword
template<class T> template<enum Outer<T>::InnerType I>  int Outer<T>::template Inner<I>::x =0;

Working demo

C++17
You we can use inline to provide the definition inside the class.
template <class T>
class Outer
{
private:
  enum InnerType {foo, bar /* etc */};
  
  template <InnerType U>
  class Inner
  {
  public:
//--vvvvvv-------------------->with c++17
    inline static int x = 0;
  };
//other code as before
};


rejected by clang Demo

@Jarod42 Yes, I did see that, I am reporting the clang bug. WIll post a link here.

@Jarod42 Here is the clang bug: Clang rejects valid out of class definition of static data member of nested class template
